# How to return "NaN" using SQRT function in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle

How to return "NaN" using `SQRT` function in Oracle SQL?  Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
SELECT SQRT(4) AS "SQRT of 4",
       SQRT(0) AS "SQRT of 0",
       SQRT(-1) AS "SQRT of -1"
FROM DUAL;
```

As I understand, a successful query might use the [`TO_BINARY_DOUBLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions177.htm) function but additional approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the number, as you said:

```
SELECT SQRT(4) AS "SQRT of 4",
   SQRT(0) AS "SQRT of 0",
   SQRT(TO_BINARY_DOUBLE(-1)) AS "SQRT of -1"
FROM DUAL;
```